# Hiding folders in informatica

Tags: directory, repository, informatica

Is there a way to hide folders with in Informatica Repository Manager? We still want the folders so do not want to delete them, however we do not want other sources system folder on show.

Answer (score 0):

Folders will not be visible to users/groups lacking Read access to it. With the folder highlighted, select Folder > Edit > Permissions to remove Read access. If you are wanting to hide from the Admins you will need to get creative with groups and role permissions.